# Ёлка на конcоли

Tags: c#, алгоритм, консоль

Нужно реализовать вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Написал код:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AnotherTriangle ob = new AnotherTriangle();
        ob.CreateTriangle();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class AnotherTriangle
{
    int n;
    string result = "*";
    public void CreateTriangle()
    {
    flag1:
        Console.Write("Введите желаемую количество треугольников: ");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
        if (n <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Неправильный ввод данных\n"); goto flag1;
        }
        string s = "*".PadLeft(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            s = s.Substring(1) + "**";
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге получилась башня, но никак не равнобедренные треугольники.

Прошу помочь или навести на дельную мысль. Причём нужно, чтобы пользователь мог вводить произвольное количество треугольников.

Comment: Вы также можете ознакомиться с моими решениями вашей задачи по следующей ссылке http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-0-00000069-000-0-0-1443610471

Comment: @Discord , это будет полезно. Отдельное спасибо да детальные комментарии. Становясь чуть более опытными, люди забывают, что не всё для них всегда было "очевидным".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как я уже ответил на Ваш вопрос [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842466/c-sharp-christmas-tree/32842708#32842708), копирую сюда ответ:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите желаемое количество треугольников: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        string branch = new String('*', j);
        Console.WriteLine(branch.PadLeft(n + 3) + "*" + branch);
    }
}
```

[Рабочий пример.](https://ideone.com/azXVFq)

Comment: Вы генерируете слишком много мусора в памяти.

Comment: @Discord *слишком много* — по каким критериям? Вы собираетесь генерировать ёлочки на сотню тысяч строк? Или думаете, что перед топик-стартером сейчас стоит задача оптимизировать работу с памятью?

Comment: "Слишком много" относительно тупого решения в лоб, при котором можно вычислить количество звёздочек сразу, а не строить строку с N звёздочек, конкатенировать с собой, а потом добавлять ещё одну. Это подаёт плохой пример, вычислить `j*2+1` можно сразу.

Comment: Моей задачей (которую я, впрочем, сам перед собой поставил) было написать как можно более чёткий, понятный и читабельный алгоритм, который бы показал человеку, изучающему программирование, логичное решение его задачи. Возможно, я в чём-то вас не допонял — если вы можете предложить улучшение в моём решении, которое бы сохранило или улучшило краткость и ясность, я с удовольствием отредактирую свой ответ.

Comment: @Discord если вас заботит выделение памяти, то можно вообще не создавать новых строк, а вместо этого циклами выводить в консоль `' '` и `'*'`. Но вы ведь этого не делаете в своём решении.

Comment: Вызов `new String('*', j * 2 + 1).PadLeft(n + 3)` мне видится более простым и логичным, чем разделение на какие-то "ветки". Если выводить посимвольно, то там уже тормоза вывода в консоль выползут, подозреваю. Если бы меня реально заботила память, я бы выделил одну строку, а потом через unsafe менял в ней символы. :)

Comment: `new String('*', j * 2 + 1).PadLeft(n + 3)`, к сожалению, выровняет все слои дерева по правой стороне. Сработает так, как в вашем решении: `new String(' ', n - j) + new String('*', j * 2 + 1)`. Но топик-стартер выбрал моё решение, видимо, потому, что оно ему было понятнее. Поэтому я не буду заменять свой подход на ваш, иначе получится два практически одинаковых ответа.

Answer (score 5):

Ладно, я сегодня добрый:

```
using static System.Console;
class ChristmasTree {
    static void Main() {
        int size;
        Write("Enter size: ");
        while (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out size) || size <= 0)
            Write("Enter size, damn it: ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                WriteLine(new string(' ', size - j) + new string('*', j * 2 - 1));
    }
}
```

Но вообще-то надо писать так:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;
using static System.Int32;
using static System.String;
class ChristmasTree {
    static void Main() {
        int size;
        Write("Enter size: ");
        while (!TryParse(ReadLine(), out size) || size <= 0)
            Write("Enter size, damn it: ");
        WriteLine(Join("\n", Range(1, size).SelectMany(i => Range(1, i),
            (i, j) => new string(' ', size - j) + new string('*', j * 2 - 1))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/zN1QI3

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 10;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        string temp;

        for (int q=0; q<n; ++q)
            for (int w=0; w<=q; ++w)
                sb.Append(temp = new string(' ', n-w-1)).Append(new string('*', 2*w+1)).Append(temp).AppendLine();

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Вместо создания строк можно добавлять символы в цикле.

Comment: Вы ввод параметра посеяли, он в оригинале тоже криво реализован.

Comment: @Discord, а с чего я должен писать ввод параметра?